# The command '/bin/sh -c npm install && npm ls' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: node.js, docker

> Basically I'm trying to live [debug my node project which is inside the Docker container](https://blog.docker.com/2016/07/live-debugging-docker/). I'm completely new to Docker also

I have an existing nodejs express based API project which I wanted to move to [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /code

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package.json /code/package.json
RUN npm install && npm ls
RUN mv /code/node_modules /node_modules

COPY . /code

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Finally, `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: nodemon --debug=5858
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5858:5858"
```

Now, when I start the app using `docker-compose up` - it throws this error:

```
Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install && npm ls' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I have tried to [explicitly install node / npm in my container before running npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49088882/2404470) but still the same problem.

Here is the complete stack trace after `docker build -t project-name .`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  360.9MB
Step 1/7 : FROM node:latest
 ---> 451b716593e5
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /code
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b94de1bb15a2
Step 3/7 : RUN npm install -g nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 19fee55fb68b
Step 4/7 : COPY package.json /code/package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ded2bb55f958
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install && npm ls
 ---> Running in 60c516514d02
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@1.0.3: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes
npm WARN deprecated boom@5.2.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated joi@13.7.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@5.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated joi@6.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@1.1.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()

> phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /code/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
> node install.js

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Saving to /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Receiving...

Received 22866K total.
Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
Removing /code/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1560259586773/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /code/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /code/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /code/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v72-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@12.4.0 (node-v72 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.3/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.3-node-v72-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.3 and node@12.4.0 (node-v72 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
make: Entering directory '/code/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
make: Entering directory '/code/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
bcrypt_lib.target.mk:109: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/code/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR!  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
 stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /code/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/code/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /code/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
Assembler messages:
Error: can't open /code/node_modules/bcrypt/ccwfjQgR.s for reading: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o] Error 1
bcrypt_lib.target.mk:109: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/code/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/code/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /code/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN backend@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-06-11T13_26_35_611Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install && npm ls' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Adding ajv as suggested by the above stack trace:

```
npm install ajv@^2.1.1 --save
```

Which for some reasons is not installing.

Does anyone know what is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Try to run `docker build` separately (not by running `docker-compose up`). You should have more logs about the failing step (`npm install && npm ls`).

Comment: unable to reproduce. worked perfectly for me. although you probably noticed you little volumes problem... (when you mount your dir to `/code`, everything inside `/code` is overwritten, including `node_modules` youve just installed...) i dont think that is what causing your current problem but it might put you in troubles later. good luck anyway

Comment: CMD ["sh","-c", "npm start"]

Comment: @TruongDang Still the same problem :(

Comment: @norbjd `docker build -t project-name .` results in the same error but the stack trace seems to be giving some insights

Comment: @norbjd Added the stack trace